# On Android, Garbage Collection done per process or system wide?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

In the log, when you see something such as:

```
DEBUG/dalvikvm(####): GC freed 5052 objects / 577400 bytes in 54ms
```

Does it mean that it freed 5052 objects that my application itself created or could some of those 5052 objects be ones that other applications running in the background created?

Comment: Since you're asking about GC, are you having memory issues, or was this question just out of curiosity?  You may want to read these Android Dev articles about memory if you're encountering problems: http://bit.ly/h9B3Oj  http://bit.ly/a9LCoV

Comment: @NotDaveLane, for the sake of keeping this on one topic, yes it is out of curiosity as a means to better understand the feedback and information the system is providing me.  Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number in parens is the process number that the garbage collector is running for. You can either do a ps from the shell or check DDMS to find out the process number for your application. Filter by the process number to see on the garbage collection happening for the VM instance running your app.

Answer (score 2):

On Android, every application runs in its own process, each of which runs in its own virtual machine (VM). The GC your viewing is specific to your application and so the info belongs to your app alone.

Dalvik VM use a tracing garbage collector [(Mark & Sweep Approach)](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page424.html).